# Change Specific Name in Record

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a column name `Address`. The record Exist in this column is something like `ABC,XYZ,TX`

What is the query to write `Texas` instead of `TX` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? What is the table name, column name and what is the condition?

Comment: Lets say Table Name is EMPLOYEE column name as mentioned ADDRESS and the condition is I want to replace TEXAS instead of TX i.e; I want "ABC,XYZ,Texas" this output

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when address like '% TX'
             then concat(left(address, length(address) - 2), 'Texas')
             else address
        end)
```

That said, you should be storing the state in a separate column.

Comment: Is There is another way basically I am a beginner I can't understand this

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to rewrite every `TX`, in the column `Adress` of your table, by `Texas`. This is the SQL query to achieve that.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Address = replace(Address , 'TX', 'Texas')
WHERE Address LIKE '%TX'
```

Comment: I want this"ABC,XYX,TEXAS"

Comment: I specifically want to change TX

Comment: I updated the answer to include it

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality, you may want to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want update the value you could use arepalce in update

```
update Your_Table
set Address = replace(Address, 'TX', 'Texas')  
where Address   like '%TX%'
```

or for final match

```
update Your_Table
set Address = replace(Address, 'TX', 'Texas')  
where Address  like '%TX'
```

or if you need only a select

```
 select  replace(Address, 'TX', 'Texas')  address
 from Your_Table
 where Address   like '%TX%'
```

Comment: This cannot be worked

Comment: answer updated  .. removing wrong = like

Comment: Query runs but it cannot changed TX.

Comment: have you tried  the versione without =   ???

Comment: No bro I never try that

Answer (score 0):

`TX` can be in any part of the string, and you don't want in a string like this:

> ABC**TX**D,XYZ,**TX**

the 1st occurrence of TX to be replaced, right?
So to cover all cases you need to concatenate `,` to the start and the end of the string and then make the replacement:

```
update tablename
set address = trim(',' FROM replace(
  concat(',', address, ','), 
  concat(',','TX', ','), 
  concat(',', 'Texas', ',')
)) 
where concat(',', address, ',') like concat('%,', 'TX', ',%')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ma1ZwTvW99LzUcCSmjhUtD/1).